# why --not <or> to infinitive in "indirect speech"

Tags: indirect-speech

> 1.He asked me why I didn't run and fetch the doctor.
>
> 2.He asked me to run and fetch the doctor.

I wanted to know which sentence is more natural and formal for reprted speech.

Comment: Why not? I am puzzled as to why @Josh has deleted his answer.

Comment: Why not include in your question the research you've done? :)

Comment: I think Longman is referring to "Why not?" as an entire reply to a question. Your example just uses uses why and not in the same sentence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a misinterpretation of a reference book.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: You have written a new question. And your new one doesn't allow the breezy suggestion sense ('Why don't you go for a nice cooling dip?')  for 'He asked me why I didn't run and fetch the doctor.'

Comment: As it currently stands, neither the title nor the body of this question makes sense. The title in particular is bafflingly incomprehensible. What is “why --not <or> to infinitive” supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3):

In answer to OP's original [amended here]

> According to Longman Dictionary [reference needed],
>
> *"Why not" is a "spoken phrase" used to say that you agree with a suggestion.*
>
> My question is: Can I use *Why not?* in 'formal writing' as in the
>   following sentence:
>
> We then thought we might investigate whether an increase in the
>   temperature resulted in a better yield. Why not?

According to Wordreference.com:

**why not** *interj*    *informal*

(expressing openness to try [sth])